# Creating template from different block in django?

Tags: python, django, templates, django-templates, django-views

I am trying to create a single page with different content from different template in django so i can print it. Its kind of summary of different page

- **base.html** - mainContent block is rendered inside this template
- **main.html** - Need mainContent block from here
- **graph.html** - Need mainContent block from here
- **charts.html** - Need mainContent block from here
- **summary.html** -  Need content from main, graph, charts all together here *(REQUIRE)*

I have a base template which is extended on every page like this (It has navbar, footer and sidebar)

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
```

There is a block inside base template where graph, main, chart content is displayed. What i am trying to accomplish is to get the mainContent from those page and add it to new template called **summary.html**

Since every page is extending from base i am not sure how to do that? I tried using include but it will also include base for every page.

EDIT: I know i can separate the mainContent into its own separate files but i have lot of templates and was looking for any other solutions.

Answer (score 1):

You could separate the content.

I guess you have something like this:

```
<!-- graph.html -->
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block 'mainContent'%}
    {# Your graphs html here #}
{% endblock %}
```

But you could put the *graph html* in a separate, let's say `graph_template.html` template and include it:

```
<!-- graph.html -->
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block 'mainContent'%}
    {% include 'graph_template.html' %}
{% endblock %}
```

And then in *summary.html* you can include `graph_template.html`.

Comment: I know i can do that. But this was just an  example with three template but i have a lot of templates and was looking for any other solution